# Innodb: Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list when queried more than 1 columns

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

I'm trying to run a very simple query on my MySQL INNODB table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM items 
WHERE MATCH (item_title,item_description) AGAINST ('dog')
```

Both column `item_title` and `item_description` have a `FULLTEXT` index.

I keep getting this error:

> Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

**My issue:** when I query *just* `item_title` or *just* `item_description` then it works fine. But when I do both at once in 1 query, as shown above, I get that error.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Probably duplicate question, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117005/mysql-full-text-search-across-multiple-tables)

Comment: That is regarding multiple tables. I'm just querying one table. Just 2 columns. So that doesn't help me unfortunately.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a third index:

```
FULLTEXT(item_title, item_description)
```

Comment: please, I have the same problem, can you improve it with example ? thanks

Comment: @GabrieleCarbonai - apparently our problem has some difference.  So, start your own question, be sure to include your particulars, plus any differences.

Answer (score 18):

I might be late, just post here in case of someone get confuse :)

Run this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `items` ADD FULLTEXT(`item_title`,`item_description`);
```

Then you are able to run full-text search:

```
SELECT * 
FROM items 
WHERE MATCH (item_title,item_description) AGAINST ('dog')
```

Answer (score 5):

If you set full-text index for individual col that works. Say

```
ALTER TABLE `items` ADD FULLTEXT(`item_title`);
ALTER TABLE `items` ADD FULLTEXT(`item_description`);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD FULLTEXT (`item_title` ,`item_description`);
    and then ( "SELECT table_name.*,
    MATCH (item_title, item_description) AGAINST ('" . $search . "') AS relevance
    FROM table_name
    WHERE MATCH (item_title, item_description) AGAINST ('" . $search . "')
    ORDER BY relevance DESC" );
```

Answer (score 1):

It will need one more index, combination of both column.

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD FULLTEXT INDEX title_desc_index (item_title, item_description);
```

After that you can run your query

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE MATCH (item_title,item_description) AGAINST ('dog')
```